# How to click particular element in android app?

Tags: appium, inspector

1. I have furnished the full details regarding the locator elements, which I have acquired from the appium inspector for android app.
2. I used text "CATEGORIES" as name and type "android.widget.TextView" as className and xpath="/android.widget.TextView[1]" in my test cases.
3. These are the possibilities I have tried it. But, the click action doesn't happens for me.
4. How can I use the locator to click the particular element?

   > DETAILS:
   >
   > content-desc:
   >   type: android.widget.TextView 
   >   text: CATEGORIES 
   >   index: 0
   >   enabled: true 
   >   visible: false 
   >   location: {0, 77} 
   >   size: {406, 42}
   >   checkable: false 
   >   checked: false 
   >   focusable: false 
   >   long-clickable: false
   >   package: com.vivi.droid.qa 
   >   password: false resource-id:null
   >   scrollable: false 
   >   selected: false 
   >   xpath:
   >   //android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on element using path:

Sample code

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIASecureTextField[1]').click()
```

I use python, if you use any other language code might differ a bit in syntax

Comment: use this code:
driver.findElementsByxpath("/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v4.view.ViewPager[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.TextView[1]").click()

Comment: can you please share inspector snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have tried and click() is not working. I would suggest below solution:

**Solution 1 -**

- You should check and confirm whether that element have property **clickable = TRUE**
  [ If that element is clickable, then go for next solution ]

**Solution 2 -**

- driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='CATEGORIES']")).click();
- driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'CATEGORIES'])")).click();
- driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'CATEGORIES'] and @index='1')")).click();